# Django ORM analogue for MS SQL rank - partition by clause

Tags: django, orm

Suppose I want to render a table in my Django template containing three columns. The first column contains student name and surname, the second column - student's university, and the third column is for the total number of students in the Univesity

```
Student  University  University statistics

John       Oxford    13
Micheal    MIT       10
Sally      Oxford    13
Steven     MIT       10
Jessica    Harvard   8
```

Currently, I have a custom method defined in my Student model which looks something like this:

```
class Student(models.Model)
    university = models.ForeignKey(University,....)

class University(models.Model)
    # university characteristics

    def get_student_count(self)
         return Student.objects.filter(university =self).count()
```

Template:

```
<table>
   ...
   {{student.university.get_student_count}}
   ...
</table>
```

In this simplified method where count is more or less cheap operation, this approach solves the problem. But if some complex and expensive operation is done in the get_student_count method, then I am concerned by the fact that I have to repeatedly hit the database and load server by the same calculation which it has already done once (f.e., when rendering John, I've calculated count for Oxford, and I want to avoid calculating it the second time for Sally). I wonder if there's any solution that Django provides to make this code a bit clearer and optimal. The odds are that a similar question has been already asked, simply I am new to Advanced topics of Django and I just want to understand which direction to dig deeper.