# Django ORM - maximizing by one field and getting values of another field in champion rows

Tags: django-orm

This is the [second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802919/django-orm-analogue-for-ms-sql-rank-partition-by-clause) I am asking such question, but because the previous post wasn't answered, I'll just try to be a bit more specific.

Consider the table below:

```
id     text       dialog_id  Timestamp

666    Hi         11         2017-01-21
667    How're u?  11         2017-01-01
668    Never      26         2016-03-01
669    Say        26         2016-03-04
770    Never      26         2016-03-29
```

The corresponding ORM model looks like this:

```
class Dialog(models.Model):
    pass

class MessageBody(models.Model):
    dialog = models.ForeignKey(Dialog, models.DO_NOTHING)
    text = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

For each dialog, I want to get the ids of messages with latest timestamps within their dialog. So the desired output for the example above should be:

`[666, 770]`

Why? Because `666` has the greatest timestamp(`2017-01-21`) within dialog with dialog_id = 11, and `770` - is the champion within dialog with dialog_id = 26.

I don't want to believe that Django tools do not suffice for this and I have to go for pure-sql query. Help me please.

Comment: Why closed ? It's been a year I can't solve this issue ))